# How to send message to newly created window tab using chrome.windows.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created a new chrome window tab via extension but I can't send message to its content script, the event never fired

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "run") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: 'https://vnexpress.net/',
            active: false
        }, function (tab) {
            chrome.windows.create({
                tabId: tab.id,
                type: 'popup',
                focused: true
            }, function (win) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(win.tabId, { action: "scrape" });
            });
        });
    }

    sendResponse();
})
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action == "scrape") {
        alert("Scraping!!!");
        console.log("Scraping")
        //This never run
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic seems to be correct, but probably `sendMessage` is being called *before* content_script.js is run.

To verify this, use `console.log(new Date)` before the `sendMessage` line and another one in the content script. You can then compare the dates.

If that's the issue, you could have the content script message the background script when it loads instead, so there's no *race condition.*

Answer (score 0):

I have put `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(win.tabId, { action: "scrape" })` in setTimeout and it worked for me

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "run") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: 'https://vnexpress.net/',
            active: false
        }, function (tab) {
            chrome.windows.create({
                tabId: tab.id,
                type: 'popup',
                focused: true
            }, function (win) {
                setTimeout(() => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(win.tabId, { action: "scrape" }); 
    }, 1000);
            });
        });
    }

    sendResponse();
})
```